# Putting a limit on doctrine queries

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a site to make an inventory of series.

```
public function category(string $categoryName): Response
{
    $categoryInfos = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Category::class)
        ->findOneByName($categoryName);

    $programs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Program::class)
        ->findByCategory($categoryInfos);

    return $this->render('wild/category.html.twig', ['programs' => $programs, 'category' => $categoryInfos]);
}
```

This function allows me to retrieve all programs belonging to the specified category.
I would now like to limit the number of programs to 3 in my request.

```
$programs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Program::class)
        ->findByCategory($categoryInfos)
        ->setMaxResults(3);
```

But this shows me the error: 
-> Call to a member function setMaxResults() on array

What did I do wrong?
I get lost in the symfony doc, being new ^^

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe `findByCategory` returns an array, as given? You should probably write a custom method in your repository that does exactly what you want, instead of chaining calls somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method inside repository class that returns an array and you cannot execute setMaxResults() on arrays.

If you want to set the size of result you should set it inside findByCategory() method in ProgramRepository.php

Comment: More correctly, `setMaxResults` is a function of `QueryBuilder`. So you want to call `setMaxResults` before calling `getQuery` within `findByCategory()`. Reason for this is that `getQuery` will return an instance of Query